# Using CCParticleFire with CCFollow

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I use `CCFollow` to keep player position center of screen.
And, I also use `CCParticleFire` as player's child node.

Problem is, when player runnning, particle don't represent particle's afterimage.
(Particles was not affected by player's move.)
(Particles remain several seconds in position where player was standing if I don't use `CCFollow`.)

I want to affect player's move to particles.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: have you added particle effect on player?? `[player addChild:particleEffect];`

Comment: Yes, particle effect follows player. But compare with situation that isn't using CCFollow, particle effect isn't affected by force in x direction.